# Can anyone help me replace this Segment with a Modal in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

can anyone help me to replace this Segment with Modal in React JS, here is the code, thanks in advance

```
return (
    <Segment clearing style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '20px', backgroundColor: '#f5f7fb'}}> ADD APPOINTMENT
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
            <Form.Input placeholder='Customer Name' value={appointment.customerName} name='customerName' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input type='date' placeholder='Appointment Date' value={appointment.appointmentDate} name='appointmentDate' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Doctor Name' value={appointment.doctorName} name='doctorName' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Service' value={appointment.service} name='service' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Status' value={appointment.status} name='status' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Button onClick={submitting} floated='right' positive type='submit' content='Submit' />
            <Button onClick={closeForm} floated='right' type='submit' content='Cancel' />
        </Form>
    </Segment>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

The below package seems perfect for your needs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal

below can be your implementation

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const customStyles = {
  content: {
    top: '50%',
    left: '50%',
    right: 'auto',
    bottom: 'auto',
    marginRight: '-50%',
    transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  },
};

// Make sure to bind modal to your appElement (https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/accessibility/)
Modal.setAppElement('#root');

function App() {
  let subtitle;
  const [modalIsOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

  function openModal() {
    setIsOpen(true);
  }

  function afterOpenModal() {
    // references are now sync'd and can be accessed.
    subtitle.style.color = '#f00';
  }

  function closeModal() {
    setIsOpen(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openModal}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onAfterOpen={afterOpenModal}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
        style={customStyles}
        contentLabel="Example Modal"
      >
    <Segment clearing style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: '20px', backgroundColor: '#f5f7fb'}}> ADD APPOINTMENT
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
            <Form.Input placeholder='Customer Name' value={appointment.customerName} name='customerName' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input type='date' placeholder='Appointment Date' value={appointment.appointmentDate} name='appointmentDate' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Doctor Name' value={appointment.doctorName} name='doctorName' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Service' value={appointment.service} name='service' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Form.Input placeholder='Status' value={appointment.status} name='status' onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <Button onClick={submitting} floated='right' positive type='submit' content='Submit' />
            <Button onClick={closeForm} floated='right' type='submit' content='Cancel' />
        </Form>
    </Segment>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, Document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29282249)

Comment: @slideshowp2 Thank you for the input,I have made the respective changes